# Does this kind of partition have a name?

Tags: terminology, convex-geometry, polyhedra, set-partition, dissection

[Note: Reposting from OR Stackexchange as advised there.](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9880/9880)

Consider a convex polyhedron $A$. Assume we have subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of $A$ that are themselves covex polyhedra and are mutually disjoint except maybe sharing an edge, and that their union gives $A$.
A simple example would be $A=[0,10]$ with $A_1=[0,3]$, $A_2=[3,6]$ and $A_3=[6,10]$ (observe $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint except for a common extreme point, and so are $A_2$ and $A_3$, and their union gives $A$).

What do we call this sort of partition-like subdivision of $A$ (in addition to a "cover")?

Comment: In 1D (as in your example), it's "sharing a point". "sharing one edge" is for 2D (as you say it). But for 3D, is it **sharing a face** ?

Comment: To follow up on @JeanMarie 's point: "Polyhedron" means in 3D. You cannot partition a 3D polyhedron into pieces that only share edges, they must instead share faces. Then I think it might be called a packing of the polyhedron $A$ by convex polyhedra. Or maybe "tiling" but with all tiles possibly incongruent.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke That usage of "polyhedron" is not universal.  In optimization, a polyhedron is an intersection of a finite number of half-spaces and can have any number of dimensions.